# Sending an email with HTML Format

Tags: php, email, attachment

I have a HTML page template to be sent as an e-mail using PHP,

Here is my code;

```
include 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Username = "secret"; // 
        $mail->Password = 'super-password';
        $mail->SetFrom("info@gmail.com", "It's me");
        $mail->AddAddress("...@gmail.com","..."); 
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->Subject = 'Hi there';

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        // Set the body
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->addAttachment("phpmailer/EmailTemplate1.html");

        //send the message, check for errors
        if ($mail->send()) {
            json_encode( array(
                    "success" => "mail ok"));
        } else {
            json_encode( array(
                    "error" => "mail error --> "  . $mail->ErrorInfo ));
        }
```

Now, Suppose that I am aimed to send "google.com" main page via e-mail, but it should appear just like it is. How can I do this ?

Secondly, Suppose that I am aimed to change something inside the mail, for example, there is written "Hey I am here to help you" in the google's search text area.

How can I code these staffs ?

Thank you.

Comment: you have syntax errors if that's what you're really using for code `'It's me'`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, I was deleting my personal info (mail, pass etc.), maybe it causes the syntax problem. The thing is that I don't have any idea how to send an e-mail as html.

Comment: If you want to send an `HTML` email, just select proper `Content-Type` header and put `HTML` code in the body. If you want to send a page of specific website, then just send the link to it.

Comment: So what's inside `EmailTemplate1.html`? if that doesn't contain full and proper HTML markup, then it will fail. I answered a similar question like this a few times, where they didn't have the right markup. What about this `$body`, where does that come into the picture?

Comment: you can ping me if you want, I'm closing this tab. good luck

Comment: $body="I am here to help you". EmailTemplate1.html contains "google.com" template. I am now trying your suggestion. Thank you, I will comment here again